# Automate directory tree creation based on date

Tags: windows, file-management, cmd.exe

Hi and thanks in advance.  I'm new to batch scripting and would like to perform the following action daily in my server.  I need to make sure the directory path `year/month/day` exists in a given subfolder, if not create it.

I researched online but I could only find scripts that make `yyyymmdd` type directory names and create only one level in the directory tree structure.

I found the following example in this [blog](http://tech.deepumohan.com/2011/09/windows-batch-script-to-create.html).

```
:: Auto directory date batch (MMDDYYYY format)
:: First parses month, day, and year into mm , dd, yyyy formats and then combines to be  DDMMYYYY
:: Setups %date% variable
:: @author Deepu Mohan Puthrote www.deepumohan.com
@echo off
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/" %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET dd=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yyyy=%%B
SET date=%dd%%mm%%yyyy%
echo New folder name %date%
MKDIR %date%
```

Comment: Please post such example, so we can try to modify it

Comment: If you mean is creating a folder named "YYYY/MM/DD", Its not possible. because you cant use Slash/BackSlash characters in folder name, if not so, please tell the details.

Comment: I don't mean one folder with slash characters, I mean a path of directories.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables to hold the info then call it to make the directory structure. I've used the following as part of a script to backup some basic files to a similar directory structure as you described.

```
set drive=C:\temp
set year=%date:~10,4%
set month=%date:~4,2%
set day=%date:~7,2%

if not exist "%drive%\%year%\%month%\%day%" MD "%drive%\%year%\%month%\%day%"
```

For instance, today this will check to see if the directories exist, then create the directory structure `C:\temp\2013\08\23` if it doesn't.

Comment: It created this directory structure: `C:\temp\8\01`